# Adding where and sum to lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have the below Linq query:

```
var qry = from Output in db.Outputs
          join ShiftHours in db.ShiftHourses on Output.ShiftHour equals ShiftHours.ShiftHour
          join ShiftData in db.ShiftDatas on Output.ShiftID equals ShiftData.ShiftID
          where ShiftData.ShiftDate == date && ShiftData.Line == line
          select new ProgressData()
          {
              CPM = ShiftData.CPM,
              Target = ShiftData.Target,
              CurrentOutput = db.Outputs.Sum(x=>x.Quantity),
              PercentOfTarget = (db.Outputs.Sum(x=>x.Quantity) / ShiftData.Target) * 100
          };
```

It is almost doing what I want but as it stands, the CurrentOutput lambda expression is returning the sum of the entire Quantity column of the Output table as I am unsure how to add in a 'Where' clause as well as the sum function (and hence the PercentOfTarget is also incorrect).

The where clause needs to be the same as the first where clause (date and line are parameters passed to the method):

```
where ShiftData.ShiftDate == date && ShiftData.Line == line
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT: Clarification of CurrentOutput.**

In the 'Output' table there can be multiple records for a given 'ShiftData.ShiftDate' and 'ShiftData.Line' combination so I would like to calculate a sum of the 'Output' table 'Quantity' column  values for a specified 'ShiftDate' and 'Line'

**EDIT: Further clarification**

This is some sample data from the Output table (OutputID is an auto-increment PK):

[image]

```
public class Output
{
    [Key]
    public int OutputId { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ShiftHour { get; set; }

    public virtual ShiftData ShiftData { get; set; }
}
```

This is some sample data from the ShiftData table (ShiftID is an auto-increment PK, there will be more than one record for each date as further line numbers are added):

[image]

```
public class ShiftData
{
    [Key]
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public int CPM { get; set; }
    public double Target { get; set; }
}
```

So using the above sample data, I am trying to populate a ProgressData object:

```
public class ProgressData
{
    public int CPM { get; set; }
    public double Target { get; set; }
    public int CurrentOutput { get; set; }
    public double PercentOfTarget { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the sample data, I would expect my ProgressData object created for line 1 on 13/2/2014 to be populated as such:

> CPM = 5, Target = 200, CurrentOutput = 120, PercentOfTarget = 60

Comment: Can you specify what you want to calculate as CurrentOutput? Why it has to be SUM?

Comment: Apologies, I did not make it clear in the original question. I have updated the question. Hopefully this makes more sense now

Comment: So, if you have several `Output` objects with same shift date and line, then you want **each** of these object to have sum of all quantities  of objects with same shift date and line?

Comment: It really sounds like there should be a `group ... into` expression in your query. Right now it just isn't making sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, no. The objective of this query is to create a new ProgressData object. This ProgressData object contains CurrentOutput. I would like to populate CurrentOutput with a sum of all the Quantities of the Output objects for a given shift date and line. I can post the objects and table data if this would help clarify?

Comment: @Jimsan - I think you do need to post the objects and table data. It's still not making sense to me. And the lack of answers makes it obvious that it's not making sense to everyone else either.

Comment: I've added some sample data. Apologies for not explaining it very well in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for that purpose :

```
var qry = from ShiftData in db.ShiftDatas
          join Output in db.Outputs on ShiftData.ShiftID equals Output.ShiftID
          into ShiftGroup 
          where ShiftData.ShiftDate == date && ShiftData.Line == line
          select new ProgressData()
          {
              CPM = ShiftData.CPM,
              Target = ShiftData.Target,
              CurrentOutput = ShiftGroup.Sum(x=>x.Quantity),
              PercentOfTarget = (ShiftGroup.Sum(x=>x.Quantity) / ShiftData.Target) * 100
          };
```

Another thing, I can't see why you need to do join with ShiftHours here, since none of it's property used in select statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree, I no longer have need for the ShiftHours join. I was using that as a reference but it can be removed now. Just as you posted this I managed to get it working myself (I will post my answer below) but I'm going to try your answer now as it seems tidier than mine

Comment: Made slight amendment to first join statement as it was not compiling as is. Now working fine and will mark as answer as it's better than my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Jimsan - I thought you probably needed a `group ... into`, but a `join ... into` is just as good.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @har07 posted I managed to get it working using the below. I am posting this for reference as it does answer the original question but I'm going to try and use @har07's code as it's tidier than mine.

```
var qry = (from Output in db.Outputs
                       join ShiftHours in db.ShiftHourses on Output.ShiftHour equals ShiftHours.ShiftHour
                       join ShiftData in db.ShiftDatas on Output.ShiftID equals ShiftData.ShiftID
                       where ShiftData.ShiftDate == date && ShiftData.Line == line
                       select new
                       {
                           ShiftData.ShiftDate,
                           ShiftData.Line,
                           ShiftData.CPM,
                           ShiftData.Target,
                           Output.Quantity
                       }).ToList();

            var progress = qry.GroupBy(l => l.ShiftDate).Select(g => new ProgressData()
            {
                CPM = g.Where(c => c.ShiftDate == date && c.Line == line).Select(c => c.CPM).FirstOrDefault(),
                Target = g.Where(c => c.ShiftDate == date && c.Line == line).Select(c => c.Target).FirstOrDefault(),
                CurrentOutput = g.Where(c => c.ShiftDate == date && c.Line == line).Sum(c => c.Quantity),
                PercentOfTarget = g.Where(c => c.ShiftDate == date && c.Line == line).Sum(c => (c.Quantity / c.Target) * 100)
            });

            return progress.FirstOrDefault();
```